# Controller without the controller suffix

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, attributerouting

based on my design requirements, I will like to exclude the suffix 'Controller' from my controllers and replace it with 'Resource'. So that 'FundsController' will become 'FundsResource'.

The problem is that I am not able to route to my specified actions by either convention based or attribute routing when I change replace the term 'Controller' and get an error saying that the controller with this name could not be found.

How can I satisfy the above mentioned design requirement and also be able to route without a problem? Either in Convention based or Attribute routing? Or whether if we can merge the benefits of convention based and attribute routing to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Controller" is hard-coded into the framework but you can you can create a new controller type resolver. Here is an excellent article from Filip - http://www.strathweb.com/2013/02/but-i-dont-want-to-call-web-api-controllers-controller/.